# Implied python preprocessor to intercept all paths at root?

Tags: apache-2.2

Ok: I know that many sites have a structure of:

example.com/index.php/pseudodir/pseudofile

Obviously AcceptPathInfo needs to be enabled in order for index.php to be able to make sense of any of it...

But is it possible for me to have `/` transparently represent index.php so that example.com/pseudodir/file would pass pseudodir to the real file /index.php

?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use mod_rewrite in order to do this; HTTPd adheres to the filesystem structure too tightly.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```